# AWS API Gateway Regional Custom Domain with CloudFlare not working

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-api-gateway, cloudflare, fastapi

I am deploying a rather simple FastAPI with Elastic Beanstalk using the Docker platform. I am using `root_path="/v1"` - this is important for the next steps. I have an API Gateway HTTP API with an HTTP integration pointing to the EB app, the stage is called `v1`. Up to this point everything works.

We are using Cloudflare for DNS services and I tried to make it work with the API, but failed. After reading whatever was available on StackOverflow on this topic I set up a Custom Domain Name (Regional) in API Gateway using a DNS-validated certificate. Cloudflare has a CNAME record pointing to the *API Gateway domain name*.

To sum up:

- accessing the EB URL `http://env-name.eba-12345678.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/` works,
- accessing the API Gateway API URL `https://0123456789.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1` works,
- accessing the *API Gateway domain name* `d-abcdefghij.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com` does not work (should it?) - I get 404's at whatever route, I tried various API mappings with path set to `none` or `v1`,
- accessing the domain name itself yields 521 errors on the Cloudflare side, here I have a CNAME record pointing to the `d-abcdefghij.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`, set to 'Proxied', I tried setting it to DNS only and pointing to `https://0123456789.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1`, didn't work either.